# Extra large, high visibility, cursors for windows?

Tags: windows, cursor, accessibility

I'm setting up a computer for my 95 year old mother. Her eyesight's not so good any more and she has a hard time seeing the mouse cursor. I'v got it set to the extra large size that windows has built in, but it's too hard for her to see the either white or black cursor (not enough contrast from the backgrounds).

Does anyone have a suggestion for a source for a set of extra large cursors for Windows 8 that are perhaps a bright color like red?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.axialis.com/cursorworkshop/

Comment: Not a bad idea. I may use it to add the few missing cursors to the set I found.

Comment: Bill Myers (the guy that made those cursors I found) also told me about a simple website for creating cursors at http://www.cursor.cc/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find it the first three times I searched for a cursor set, but I found one tonight.

There's a set of high visibility cursors at http://www.bmyers.com/public/high_visibility_cursors.cfm that fit the bill perfectly. They're large, bright red, and free. The set is missing the "Help Select" and "Working in Background" cursors, but has all the rest. I may spend some time and contribute the missing ones, but the new cursors are working fine for now.

My mom is finding it MUCH easier to use the mouse with these!

Thanks to Bill Myers for making those available!

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows 8.1, I believe there is no way to change the color of the mouse cursor. Others may beg to differ, but I cannot seem to find  the way to do so. You can, however, make it the opposite color of the screen itself (example would be if you were on a white screen, the cursor would be black, or if you were on a black screen, the cursor would be white). You might want to check the "ease of access" FAQs on the Microsoft website for Windows.

Comment: You can't change an existing cursor to a different color and there aren't any colored cursors provided with Win 8.1, but you can load custom cursors you provide. Custom cursors can be colorful. You have to use the old school desktop Mouse Control Panel applet to load them.